# First name field is being inserted into emails twice

Tags: php, mysql, html, preg-replace, str-replace

I am using the following code to send out emails, the problem I am having is that when I send an email, the persons name  is imported just fine as long a the fuel type, but some some reason it seems to be pulling in the $name value twice.

For example, I get emails like this being sent :

'Dear Tom Sawyer Tom Sawyer, here are your Derv prices :'

'Dear Will Simpson Will Simpson, Here are your Derv & Gas Oil Prices'

Here is a quick explanation of my values :
$templatename = the email template, this has stored in it the message to go out to the customer, plus a curly brackets named {name} and another called {fuel}.

{name} is pulled out of $name and replaced with the persons name, {fuel} pulls in the name of the template, which is the name of the fuel being used. This is done with the str_replace function.

So the result should be Dear, PERSONS NAME, here are your FUEL TYPE prices, but what I actually get is the persons name repeated twice for some reason ?.

```
              <?php
                  $formid = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET[token]);
                              $templatequery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM hqfjt_chronoforms_data_addmailinglistmessage WHERE cf_id = '$formid'") or die(mysql_error());
                              $templateData = mysql_fetch_object($templatequery);

                              $gasoiluserTemplate = $templateData->gasoilusers;
                              $dervuserTemplate = $templateData->dervusers;
                              $kerouserTemplate = $templateData->kerousers;
                              $templateMessage = $templateData->mailinglistgroupmessage;
                              $templatename = $templateData->mailinglistgroupname;


                require_once('./send/class.phpmailer.php');

               $mailer= new PHPMailer(true); //defaults to using php "mail()"; the true param means it will throw exceptions on errors, which we need to catch

               // Grab the FreakMailer class
                require_once('./send/MailClass.inc');

                // Grab our config settings
                require_once('./send/config.php');

              // Setup body
              $htmlBody = '<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
                              <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
                              <head>
                              <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
                              <style>#title {text-align:center;font-family:"Times New Roman", Times, serif; font-size:130% !important; font-weight:bold; color:#fff;} .address {color:#fff; font-size:60%; font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;}</style>
                              </head>

                              <body>
                              <div style="background:
                                                                none repeat scroll 0% 0% rgb(6, 38,
                                                                97); width:650px; height:auto;">
                              <img id="_x0000_i1030" style="padding-left:5%;padding-right:5%"
                                                                    src="http://www.chandlersoil.com/images/newsletter/header.gif"
                                                                    alt="Chandlers Oil and Gas"
                                                                    border="0" height="112"
                                                                    width="580">
                                                                    <div id="title">' . $templateMessage . '</div>
                                                                    <div style="background:#344ea2; width:501px; height:65px; margin-left:70px;"></div>

                                                                    <div style="background:#13155C; height:30px; width:501px; margin-left:70px;"></div>

                                                                    <div style="background:#fff; width:501px; height:365px; margin-left:70px;"></div>

<div style="background:
                                                                none repeat scroll 0% 0% rgb(6, 38,
                                                                97); height:60px; width:501px; margin-left:70px;"></div>    

                                                                <div style="background:#000139;height:100px; width:580px; margin-left:35px;" >
                                                                  <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="address" style="margin-left:5px;">
                                                                    <tr>
                                                                      <td valign="top" width="21%"><p><strong>Chandlers                                                    Depots</strong></p>
                                                                        <table class="address" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="87%">
                                                                          <tbody>
                                                                            <tr>
                                                                              <td width="57%"><p>Grantham</p></td>
                                                                              <td width="43%"><p>Spalding</p></td>
                                                                            </tr>
                                                                            <tr>
                                                                              <td><p>Lincoln</p></td>
                                                                              <td><p>Corby</p></td>
                                                                            </tr>
                                                                            <tr>
                                                                              <td><p> Spilsby</p></td>
                                                                              <td><p>Retford</p></td>
                                                                            </tr>
                                                                          </tbody>
                                                                        </table></td>
                                                                      <td valign="top" width="79%"><p><strong>Address<br />
                                                                        <br />
                                                                      </strong>Chandlers                                                  Oil &amp; Gas, Warren                                                  Way, Alma Park,                                                  Grantham, Lincolnshire,                                                  NG31 9SE<br />
                                                                        <br />
                                                                        <strong>TEL: </strong>08456                                                  202010 <strong>FAX:</strong> 01476                                                  568147 <strong>E-Mail: </strong><a href="mailto:websitesales@chandlersoil.com">websitesales@chandlersoil.com</a></p>
                                                                        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                                                                          <tbody>
                                                                            <tr>
                                                                              <td><p align="right"> </p></td>
                                                                            </tr>
                                                                          </tbody>
                                                                        </table></td>
                                                                    </tr>
                                                                  </table>
                                                                </div>                                                              
                              </div>
                              </body>
                              </html>
                              ';
         $textBody = "$templateData->mailinglistgroupmessage";


              // instantiate the class
              $mailer = new FreakMailer();

              // Get the user's Email
              $sql = mysql_query("SELECT leadname,businessname,email,mailtype FROM hqfjt_chronoforms_data_addupdatelead WHERE keromailinglist='$kerouserTemplate' AND dervmailinglist='$dervuserTemplate' AND gasoilmailinglist='$gasoiluserTemplate'");

              while($row = mysql_fetch_object($sql))
              {
                  // Send the emails in this loop.
                  $name = $row->leadname;
                   $businessname = $row->businessname;
                    $to_email = $row->email;
                    $mailtype = $row->mailtype;

                  if(!empty($row->businessname))
                  {
                      $name .= ' '.$row->leadname;
                  }

                  $to_name = $name;

                  if($row->mailtype == 'html')
                  {
                     $mailer->Body = str_replace(array('{name}', '{fuel}'), array($name, $templatename), $htmlBody);
                      $mailer->isHTML(true);
                      $mailer->AltBody = str_replace(array('{name}', '{fuel}'), array($name, $templatename), $textBody);
                      $mailer->AddAddress($to_email, $name);
                      $mailer->Subject = "Your Fuel Prices From Chandlers Oil & Gas";
                      $mailer->FromName = "Chandlers Oil & Gas";
                  }
                  else
                  {
                      $mailer->Body = str_replace(array('{name}', '{fuel}'), array($name, $templatename), $textBody);
                      $mailer->isHTML(false);
                      $mailer->Subject = "Your Fuel Prices From Chandlers Oil & Gas";
                      $mailer->FromName = "Chandlers Oil & Gas";
                          $mailer->AddAddress($to_email, $name);                                  
                  }

                  $mailer->Send();
                  $mailer->ClearAddresses();
                  $mailer->ClearAttachments();
                  $mailer->IsHTML(false);
                  echo "Mail sent to: $name - $to_email<br />";
              }

              ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think i see this here:

```
                  if(!empty($row->businessname))
                  {
                      $name .= ' '.$row->leadname;
                  }
```

dont you mean?

```
                  if(!empty($row->businessname))
                  {
                      $name .= ' '.$row->businessname;
                  }
```

:)

very simply, this is concatenating the undesired variable based on the desired condition.

Comment: What it is supposed to do is if the business name field is blank, it should use the firstname field instead, ideally it should be shomething like.......if businessname == '' $name = $salutation & $leadname else $name = $businessname
but I am not sure how to code the salutation AND the leadname in there, so for example if the company field is blank use MR JONES, if it isnt blank use JONES CORP.

Comment: Well above this after you fetch object, you have the $name field being set and filled with $row->leadname already, and in here your basically saying "if businessname is not blank, then please put another $row->leadname in there" as with the .= your no longer replacing, your ammending, so with the replacement code in my answer youd get something like "MR JONES JONES CORP". So what your saying is when businessname is NOT empty, use businessname instead of leadname right? Or am i mistaking?

Comment: Ahh I think I may have miss coded it to begin with, what I mean is if the leadname is blank, the business name should be used instead, if it is not blank, use salutation, leadname instead.

Comment: Hey no probs, glad to help :)

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
              if(!empty($row->businessname))
              {
                  $name .= ' '.$row->leadname;
              }
```

To:

```
              if(!empty($row->businessname))
              {
                  $name .= ' '.$row->businessname;
              }
```

Comment: What it is supposed to do is if the business name field is blank, it should use the firstname field instead, ideally it should be shomething like.......if businessname == '' $name = $salutation & $leadname else $name = $businessname
but I am not sure how to code the salutation AND the leadname in there, so for example if the company field is blank use MR JONES, if it isnt blank use JONES CORP.